# Authentication problem between ASP.Net Webforms app and a ASP.Net webservice

Tags: asp.net, web-services, webforms

I got a ASP.Net webforms app which is using Forms authentication. It needs to authenticate against a webservice which uses windows authentication (+ impersonation).

I've tried (amongst other things) to supply credentials by using:

```
service.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(myUserName, thePassword, theDomain)
```

The problem is that I get 401 from the webservice no matter what I try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that identity that the Application Pool that the Web service run on wasn't allowed to impersonate.

Answer (score 1):

I am doing exactly the same as this (by the sounds of it) and here is the way I construct the credentials.

```
var service = new MyService();
var netCredential = new NetworkCredential("user", "pwd", "domain");
var credentialCache = new CredentialCache
                          {
                              {new Uri(service.Url), "Basic", netCredential}
                          };
service.Credentials = credentialCache;
```

Comment: Which authentication methods have you activated in IIS for your webforms app and for your webservice? Which IIS version are you running?

Comment: The Web service is hosted on IIS7 and Authentication = Basic and Impersonation = true. The Web App is running on a different server which is also IIS7 and requires Windows Authentication.